PCB layout recommendation for Op-Amp
When designing a PCB for Op-amps normally there are some guidelines in the datasheet of the device. For example, for OPA838 the suggestions are:

Signal routing must be direct and as short as possible into and out of the op amp.
The feedback path must be short and direct avoiding vias if possible.
Ground or power planes must be removed from directly under the negative input and output pins of the amplifier.

Schematic:

This is my layout:

I also got this comment, that I need to remove the ground plane underneath the feedback trace to avoid adding capacitive patristic to the feedback loop , but if I do so, I will loose the return current path for the signal. Please let me know your suggestions.

R4's ID is missing on the PCB. Ditto C4. What about the output resistor I suggested from the other answer = that appears to be needed. How many board layers?

This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question. It's preferred to simply edit the old question rather than post a duplicate if you want to improve the question.

I don't think that's a correct duplicate, actually. But with so many posts in such a short time, and such narrowly-distinguished questions, it is a bit unfair to expect us to keep track of them. || Behnam: you are probably approaching the soft limits of this platform. That is: these numerous, related, narrow, and low-context questions are not very enticing towards readers, and posting more questions is not, I think, likely to land better answers. (To be clear, your pattern of posting, and content thereof, are well within community guidelines AFAIK; I'm not calling that into question.)

@ Andy aka, Thanks, I edited to layout picture, now it is clear more about the C4 and R4, the PCB is 8 layers.

@  The Photon, thanks for the hint, sure, I will do that.

@ Tim Williams, dear Tim, thank you very much for the useful feedback, yes, you are totally right, I understand, Considering I newly joined to the community I was not very familiar with the concept and how can efficiently write posts and ask question, from now on I will edit my previous post to add more information instead of posting a new one.  By the way, I really appreciate all your technical feedback so far, they were super useful. thanks.
